# Usage of updating a remote-tracking branch by a local branch

Tags: git, branch, git-remote, remote-branch

I know it is possible to create, update or delete a `remote-tracking branch` by content of a `local branch` of **current** repository. For example:

```
$ git push . :refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Which deletes `remote-tracking branch`. But is updating a `remote-tracking branch` by local branch a good practice? If yes, is there another usage of that work?

Comment: *every* push is updating a remote branch from a local branch.

Comment: I see now. What you mean by "remote branch" isn't what git means by "remote branch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define the term *remote-tracking branch*.  A remote-tracking branch is simply a reference whose full spelling starts with `refs/remotes/`, such as the `refs/remotes/origin/master` in your example.  In most normal interactions with Git, we drop the `refs/remotes/` part and just write `origin/master`, but sometimes—as with lower level, script-oriented Git commands, or when doing odd things like your example—it's necessary to spell it out completely.

Now, the *purpose* of a remote-tracking branch is to keep **track** of the ID stored in a **branch** on one of your **remote**s (hence the name).  So if we look closely at your question here:

> ... is updating remote branch by local branch a good practice?

we need to note a few things: this is not updating a "remote branch" (which we have not really defined), but rather updating a *remote-tracking* branch, i.e., one of those local entities with a name starting with `refs/remotes/`.  Let's also note here that you are specifically *deleting* a remote-tracking branch (which is a fairly severe form of updating :-) ).

Still, assuming you just dropped a word and really did mean "remote-tracking branch": is updating it this way a good practice?  Not generally, no.

Let me add a lot more background, though.  I also need to define the term *refspec* here.  A refspec is simply a pair of references (like `master` or `origin/master`, or their fully-spelled-out versions, `refs/heads/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/master` respectively) separated by a colon `:` character.  The reference on the left is called the source or *`src`*, and the one on the right is the destination or *`dst`*.  Optionally, you can prefix the pair with a plus-sign `+`, and omit at most one of *`src`* and/or *`dst`*.  If you omit *`dst`* you can, and probably should, omit the colon as well: `git fetch origin master`, for instance, is a source with no destination.  You need the colon when omitting *`src`* though: `git push origin :foo` cannot be spelled `git push origin foo`.

(What it *means* when you omit half of a refspec varies, between `git fetch` and `git push`.  I am not going to describe this completely, just enough to cover the cases of interest here.)

#### Update via `git fetch` and `git push`

Since Git version 1.8.4, both `git push` and `git fetch` will opportunistically update remote-tracking branches.  That is, if you have your Git contact remote *R* and either obtain or set its branch *B*, and your configuration says to track *B* under `refs/remotes/R/B` (as is the normal setup), your Git will (since 1.8.4) update that remote-tracking branch.  (Before 1.8.4, Git did opportunistic updates for `push` but not for `fetch`.)

#### Deleted branches and `--prune`

Simply running `git fetch origin` (with no additional refspecs) will update all your `refs/remotes/origin/` remote-tracking branches.  But suppose you did this earlier and there was an `xyz` branch that your Git had copied to `refs/remotes/origin/xyz`, and since then, someone *deleted* branch `xyz` on `origin`?

What happens today is that your Git preserves your `origin/xyz` (presumably, in case you were still using it).  To tell your Git that it should automatically *prune* any remote-tracking branch that you have, that the remote no longer has, simply add `--prune` (or `-p`) to your command:

```
$ git fetch --prune origin
```

Your Git will now *remove* any remote-tracking branch that you have listed under `origin` that is not still tracking an actual branch on the remote named `origin`.

You can also spell this:

```
git remote update --prune origin
```

and there is some bug in some version(s) of Git where one of the two commands works and the other does not (I'm not sure which versions, nor which one is successful).

#### Manual update

As a general rule, you should let Git update remote-tracking branches automatically.  There are several specific cases where you might want to update them manually, though, such as after modifying your configuration by hand to change the name of a remote, or to change the mapping applied to a remote (the `remote.remote.fetch` lines), or encountering a bug like the one I just mentioned.  Or, for instance, if you've just used a source-less `git push`, or `git push --delete`, to delete a branch—`git push origin :foo`—and you have an extremely slow network connection, you might be too impatient to run `git fetch -p origin` and wait.

In this case, while `git push . :refs/remotes/origin/foo` *does* work to delete `origin/foo` from your repository, you might as well use a more direct command:

```
$ git branch -r -d origin/foo
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/foo (was 5ace313).
```

In fact, any update to remote-tracking branches can be done through `git branch -r` (or the underlying "plumbing" command, `git update-ref`), just as updates to local branches can be done through `git branch` (without `-r`).  The only place where I believe there is good a reason to use `git push .` to update a branch is to achieve the result of `git merge --ff-only` without actually checking out the branch.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Specifically, `git push . x:y` attempts to do a fast-forward of local ID *`x`*—this can be anything that resolves to a valid object ID—with reference *`y`*.  When *`y`* is a local branch, it is the equivalent of:

```
git checkout y && git merge --ff-only x && git checkout -
```

except that it does not touch the work-tree at all.  Except for atomicity and type-checking issues and possible symbolic ref issues, it is also the equivalent of this sequence of shell commands:

```
x="$1" y="$2"
# resolve x to an object ID
xid=$(git rev-parse $x) || exit
# resolve y to a reference
yref=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $y) || exit
[ -z "$yref" ] && { echo "fatal: $y: not a valid reference"; exit 1; }
# make sure the current value of y is an ancestor of (resolved) x
git merge-base --is-ancestor $yref $xid || { echo 'not a fast forward'; exit 1; }
# ok, it is a fast forward: update
git update-ref -m "fast forward" $yref $xid
```

Note that `--symbolic-full-ref` resolves a symbolic reference like `origin/HEAD` to the name it refers-to, e.g., `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  This is probably undesirable here, but there is no obvious flag to `git rev-parse` to verify that the reference name is valid and convert it to fully-qualified, but not expand a symbolic name to its target.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking though. If you want an alternative to deleting a remote branch like that, there is this:

`git push origin --delete branchName`

When I update the remote by the local, I have made sure that the git history lines up, so that there is no force push.

When I delete the remote by the local, it is when the feature of the branch has been implemented, and the pull request to master has just been completed. All the changes in remote branch are now in master, so we can safely delete the branch.